# How can display success message in popup?

Tags: ajax, laravel

I am display success message in div of id=ajax-alert but my aim is to display this message in popup and after displaying this message in within some time popup will hide. I am confused how i am display success message in popup. How i am creating popup and how it is disable in some time?

View:

```
<div id="ajax-alert" class="alert" style="display:none"></div>
```

controller:

```
 public function add_to_wishlist(Request $req)
    {
         $userId=Session::get('userid');
         if(empty($userId))
         {
            return response()->json(['status'=> 1]);
         }
         else
         {
            $checkWishlist=DB::select('select * from wishlist where user_id=? && product_id=?',[$userId,$req->sub_id]);
             if($checkWishlist)
             {
               DB::table('wishlist')->where('user_id',$userId)->where('product_id',$req->sub_id)->delete();

               return response()->json(['status'=> 2,'message'=>'item is removed from wishlist']);              
             }
             else
             {
              DB::table('wishlist')->insert(['user_id'=>$userId,'product_id'=>$req->sub_id]);

              return response()->json(['status'=> 3,'message'=>'item is added in wishlist']);
             }
         }
    }
```

script:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  $(document).ready(function(){
  $('.sub').click(function(e) { 

    var sub_id=$(this).attr('data-id');
    var input=$(this).prev();
    e.preventDefault()
               $.ajaxSetup({
                  headers: {
                      'X-CSRF-TOKEN': $('meta[name="_token"]').attr('content')
                  }
              });
         jQuery.ajax({

                  url: "{{ url('/add-to-wishlist') }}",
                  method: 'get',
                  data: {
                     sub_id: sub_id,
                  },
                  success: function(result){
                    if(result.status==1)
                    {
                       window.location.href="/login";
                    }
                    else if(result.status==2)
                     {
                        //$('a[data-id="' + sub_id + '"] > i.whishstate').css({"color":"grey"});

                        $('a[data-id="' + sub_id + '"] > i.whishstate').removeClass("add");
                        $('a[data-id="' + sub_id + '"] > i.whishstate').addClass("remove");

                        $('#ajax-alert').addClass('alert-success').show(function(){
                          $(this).html(result.message);
                         });

                     }
                     else if(result.status==3)
                     {
                        //$('a[data-id="' + sub_id + '"] > i.whishstate').css({"color":"#FBA842"});

                        $('a[data-id="' + sub_id + '"] > i.whishstate').removeClass("remove");
                        $('a[data-id="' + sub_id + '"] > i.whishstate').addClass("add");

                          $('#ajax-alert').addClass('alert-success').show(function(){
                           $(this).html(result.message);
                         });

                     }
                  }});

  });
 });

</script>

@endsection
```

Answer (score 0):

in `ajax` you can not use `$(this)`
it's not getting you any errors or warning~, it just does not working
you can do this:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  $(document).ready(function(){
  $('.sub').click(function(e) { 
    var this_element = $(this); //THIS LINE ADDED!
    var sub_id=$(this).attr('data-id');
    var input=$(this).prev();
    e.preventDefault()
               $.ajaxSetup({
                  headers: {
                      'X-CSRF-TOKEN': $('meta[name="_token"]').attr('content')
                  }
              });
         jQuery.ajax({

                  url: "{{ url('/add-to-wishlist') }}",
                  method: 'get',
                  data: {
                     sub_id: sub_id,
                  },
                  success: function(result){
                    if(result.status==1)
                    {
                       window.location.href="/login";
                    }
                    else if(result.status==2)
                     {
                        //$('a[data-id="' + sub_id + '"] > i.whishstate').css({"color":"grey"});

                        $('a[data-id="' + sub_id + '"] > i.whishstate').removeClass("add");
                        $('a[data-id="' + sub_id + '"] > i.whishstate').addClass("remove");

                        $('#ajax-alert').addClass('alert-success').show(function(){
                          this_element.html(result.message);
                         }); //THIS LINE CHANGED!

                     }
                     else if(result.status==3)
                     {
                        //$('a[data-id="' + sub_id + '"] > i.whishstate').css({"color":"#FBA842"});

                        $('a[data-id="' + sub_id + '"] > i.whishstate').removeClass("remove");
                        $('a[data-id="' + sub_id + '"] > i.whishstate').addClass("add");

                          $('#ajax-alert').addClass('alert-success').show(function(){
                           this_element.html(result.message);
                         }); //THIS LINE CHANGED TOO!

                     }
                  }});

  });
 });

</script>
```

Comment: not working actually message is displayed in div but i want to display in popup

Answer (score 0):

To display a popup, you can use a `Modal`. You can use this `basic modal` to use as your popup:

```
    <!-- Modal -->
<div id="myModal" class="modal fade" role="dialog">
  <div class="modal-dialog">

    <!-- Modal content-->
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header">
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>
        <h4 class="modal-title">Modal Header</h4>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-body">
        <p class = 'alert-text'></p>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-footer">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
      </div>
    </div>

  </div>
</div>


<script type="text/javascript">
  $(document).ready(function(){

  $('.sub').click(function(e) { 
    var $this = $(this);
    var sub_id= $this.attr('data-id');
    var input= $this.prev();
    e.preventDefault()
               $.ajaxSetup({
                  headers: {
                      'X-CSRF-TOKEN': $('meta[name="_token"]').attr('content')
                  }
              });
         jQuery.ajax({

                  url: "{{ url('/add-to-wishlist') }}",
                  method: 'get',
                  data: {
                     sub_id: sub_id,
                  },
                  success: function(result){
                    if(result.status == 1) {
                       window.location.href="/login";
                    }
                    else if(result.status == 2) {
                        //$('a[data-id="' + sub_id + '"] > i.whishstate').css({"color":"grey"});

                        $('a[data-id="' + sub_id + '"] > i.whishstate').removeClass("add");
                        $('a[data-id="' + sub_id + '"] > i.whishstate').addClass("remove");

                         $('.alert-text').html(result.message);
                         $('#myModal').modal('show');

                     }
                     else if(result.status == 3) {
                        //$('a[data-id="' + sub_id + '"] > i.whishstate').css({"color":"#FBA842"});

                        $('a[data-id="' + sub_id + '"] > i.whishstate').removeClass("remove");
                        $('a[data-id="' + sub_id + '"] > i.whishstate').addClass("add");


                         $('.alert-text').html(result.message);
                         $('#myModal').modal('show');

                       setTimeout(function(){
                         $('#myModal').modal('hide');
                       },3000); //It will hide modal

                     }
                  }});

  });
 });

</script>
```

If you want more custom popup then you can search for `sweetAlert`.

Comment: Where have you added it?

Comment: same as you given

Comment: No, I meant where have you added it? Did you add it in `<body></body>`?

Comment: yes I am added on body tag my modal is not open on ajax success

Comment: Are you getting any errors in `console` otherwise it should have worked? Please check for errors.

Comment: $(...).modal is not a function this error is acccur

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/206413/discussion-between-rob-and-smitarani-patil).

Answer (score 0):

```
// install package
composer require brian2694/laravel-toastr
// then
php artisan vendor:publish 

// use this css cdn
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://cdn.bootcss.com/toastr.js/latest/css/toastr.min.css">
// use this js cdn

    <script src="http://cdn.bootcss.com/toastr.js/latest/js/toastr.min.js"></script>
        {!! Toastr::message() !!}

    <script>
        @if($errors->any())
            @foreach($errors->all() as $error)
                    toastr.error('{{ $error }}','Error',{
                        closeButton:true,
                        progressBar:true,
                    });
            @endforeach
        @endif
    </script>

// Controller 

use Brian2694\Toastr\Facades\Toastr;

public function store(Request $request)
    {
        $this->validate($request,[
            'name' => 'required'
        ]);

        $category = new Category();
        $category->name = $request->name;
        $category->slug = str_slug($request->name);
        $category->save();
        Toastr::success('Category Successfully Saved','Success');
        return redirect()->route('admin.category.index');
    }
```